# Lines of text as SQL Server 2008 statement input

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have lines of IP addresses and I would like to input it into

```
SELECT 
    [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
                     FROM [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
                     WHERE [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = 'line from c:\ip_list.txt') 
          THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
         ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) 
    END
FROM 
    [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
WHERE 
    [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = 'line from c:\ip_list.txt'
```

Where the output looks like

```
IP Address    Exists
10.10.10.10    1
10.10.10.11    0
10.10.10.12    1
...
```

I am testing with

```
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\ip_list.txt', SINGLE_NCLOB) MyFile
```

And it displays all the input in a single cell.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: How is the file delimited?

Comment: @Conduit It's one IP address per line, ending with empty space. Saved in UNICODE

Comment: I have a function that might help... Need to find a way to pass in a unicode newline as a delimiter, though. I'll do a quick test and get back to you.

Comment: Actually, I'm being a complete idiot. Have you tried playing with the `WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = [your row terminator here])` option?

Comment: OPENROWSET doesn't seem to have support for UNICODE, you need to use BULK INSERT with datafiletype as widenative

Comment: I tried `SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM BULK INSERT (BULK 'c:\list.txt', widenative) MyFile
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n')` and am getting syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Variable NVARCHAR(MAX)
CREATE TABLE ##TestTable (value NVARCHAR(100))
SELECT @Variable=BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\test.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) MyFile
SELECT @Variable = 'INSERT INTO ##TestTable VALUES(''' + REPLACE(@Variable,CHAR(10),'''); INSERT INTO ##TestTable VALUES(''')+''');'
EXEC( @Variable)
PRINT @Variable
SELECT * FROM ##TestTable
DROP TABLE ##TestTable
```

This is how i did it  :)

Comment: `10.10.10.10  10.10.10.11  10.10.10.12  10.10.10.13  10.10.10.14  10.10.10.15  10.10.10.16`

Comment: Replace the path with your file path and test it out.

Comment: I still need to know how to feed it into a `SELECT` statement that will output whether it exists in the database or not ... will research more